# Cannot execute AsyncTask within AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an `AsyncTask` in my code to obtain:

1. Location
2. Latitude and longitude from that location

Whenever I call the `execute()` method on my `AsyncTask`, I receive the following error.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
```

Class:

```
public class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        private Context context;
        private GetPlaces getPlaces;

        private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

        private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
        private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
        private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

        private static final String API_KEY = "key=My key";

        private String INPUT = "INPUT";

        private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        private StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
        private URL url;
        private InputStream iStream = null;

        private JSONObject jsonObject;
        private JSONArray jsonArray;

        private String description = "";

        private GetLatLong getLatLong;


        public GetPlaces(Context context, String INPUT, AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView) {
            this.context = context;
            this.INPUT = INPUT;
            this.autoCompleteTextView = autoCompleteTextView;
            this.execute(INPUT);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String response = "";

            try {
                INPUT = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            String types = "types=geocode";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = INPUT + "&" + types + "&" + API_KEY + "&" + sensor;

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            stringBuilder.append("?" + parameters);


            //connections is established here
            try {
                url = new URL(stringBuilder.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                response = sb.toString();
                Log.e("Response", response);

                br.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    iStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {




            getLatLong = new GetLatLong(context, s);
            getLatLong.execute(s);   // App crashes here


        }
```

Logcat shows it crashes on the second line of the `onPostExecute()` method. (commented).

Comment: try new  GetLatLong(context, s).execute()...on the other side check context or s...any of the two can be null..

Comment: I tried but still same error n i have checked nothing is null

Comment: just paste your logcat details.

Answer (score 0):

This will result in an endless loop. You can check out [this](http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/) post for achieving desired results.